# Visual C++ hash_multimap not finding any results

Tags: visual-c++, stl

I need some help understanding how stdext::hash_multimap's lower_bound, upper_bound and equal_range work (at least the VS2005 version of it).

I have the following code (summarized for the question)

```
#include <hash_map>

using stdext::hash_multimap;
using std::greater;
using stdext::hash_compare;
using std::pair;
using std::cout;

typedef hash_multimap < double, CComBSTR, hash_compare< double, greater<double> > > HMM;
HMM hm1;
HMM :: const_iterator it1, it2;
pair<HMM::const_iterator, HMM::const_iterator> pairHMM;

typedef pair <double, CComBSTR> PairDblStr;

// inserting only two values for sample
hm1.insert ( PairDblStr ( 0.224015748, L"#1-64" ) );
hm1.insert ( PairDblStr ( 0.215354331, L"#1-72" ) );

// Using a double value in between the inserted key values to find one of the elements in the map
it1 = hm1.lower_bound( 0.2175 );

if( it1 == hm1.end() )
{
    cout << "lower_bound failed\n";
}

it1 = hm1.upper_bound( 0.2175 );

if( it1 == hm1.end() )
{
    cout << "upper_bound failed\n";
}

pairHMM = hm1.equal_range( 0.2175 );
if( ( pairHMM.first == hm1.end() ) && ( pairHMM.second == hm1.end() ) )
{
    cout << "equal_range failed\n";
}
```

As mentioned in the comment I am passing in a value (0.2175) that is in between the two inserted key values (0.224015748, 0.215354331). But the output of the code is:

```
lower_bound failed
upper_bound failed
equal_range failed
```

Did I misunderstand how the lower_bound, upper_bound and equal_range can be used in maps? Can we not find a "closest match" key using these methods? If these methods are not suitable, would you have any suggestion on what I could use for my requirement?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Thanks to @billy-oneal @dauphic for their comments and edits. I have updated the code above to make it compilable and runnable (once you include the correct headers of course).

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, could you fix it so we can double check whether you're using it correctly? For example `if( it1 = hm1.end() )` and the line after `it1 = hm1.upper_bound( 0.2175 );`

Comment: Changed tag to visual-c++ because standard C++ does not have a hash_multimap type.

Comment: The C++0x equivalent would be unordered_multimap

Comment: @dauphic. Thanks for your suggestions. Updated code is posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we not find a "closest match" key using these methods?

No.  `hash_multimap` is implemented using a hashtable.  Two keys that are very close to each other (0.2153 and 0.2175, for example) will likely map to totally different bins in the hashtable.

A hashtable does not maintain its elements in a sorted order, so you cannot find the closest match to a given key without a linear search.

The `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, and `equal_range` functions in `hash_multimap` have a somewhat odd implementation in the Visual C++ standard library extensions.

Consider [the documentation for `lower_bound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157845.aspx):

> The member function determines the first element `X` in the controlled sequence that hashes to the same bucket as key and has equivalent ordering to key. If no such element exists, it returns `hash_map::end`; otherwise it returns an iterator that designates `X`. You use it to locate the beginning of a sequence of elements currently in the controlled sequence that match a specified key.

And [the documentation for `upper_bound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386276.aspx):

> The member function determines the last element `X` in the controlled sequence that hashes to the same bucket as key and has equivalent ordering to key. If no such element exists, or if `X` is the last element in the controlled sequence, it returns `hash_map::end`; otherwise it returns an iterator that designates the first element beyond `X`. You use it to locate the end of a sequence of elements currently in the controlled sequence that match a specified key.

Essentially, these functions allow you to identify the range of elements that have a given key.  Their behavior is *not* the same as the behavior of `std::lower_bound` or `std::map::lower_bound` (theirs is the behavior that you were expecting).

For what it's worth, the C++0x unordered associative containers do not provide `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, or `equal_range` functions.

> Would you have any suggestion on what I could use for my requirement?

Yes:  if you need the behavior of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, use an ordered associative container like `std::multimap`.

Comment: @james-mcnellis Thanks for your answer. Your suggestion to use std::multimap instead of the stdext::hash_multimap worked. The reason I assumed that the three methods did what I thought was because of the following MSDN pages: http://bit.ly/aAGAlk, http://bit.ly/ammaLF, which are different than the ones you posted - the ones you posted seem to be for CLR (i.e. Managed code, not native code). The ones I posted are the same documentation that I have in my local MSDN install. It appears that Microsoft has a documentation flaw. But your explanation was more than sufficient to solve my problem.

Comment: @ossandcad:  Oh, sorry about that.  I quoted the `hash_map` documentation, not the `hash_multimap` documentation.  Yes, the `hash_multimap` documentation is misleading at best.  It says it returns an iterator "that addresses the location succeeding the last element in the hash_multimap if no match is found for the key."  So, if no match for the key is found, it returns `end()`.  The first part of that sentence (which I didn't quote here), though, is quite confusing.